# How do I access this specific element using selenium? (Page Source included)

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, webdriver

Note; I have next to no HTML or CSS knowledge so please forgive my ignorance!

Hi all, I'm currently trying to use selenium[Java] to navigate through a website and download a file. I have been able to pass the login page, but I seem to be having trouble navigating through the site now.

[image]

I'm currently trying to "click" the last item in the list but I cant seem to reference this item nor the root in which it resides. Any help would be much appreciated!

Note; I'm using HtmlUnitDriver, does this cause conflict?

Comment: That is _hardly_ your page source... Post code examples for more help.

Comment: Sorry I didnt mean this is literally what .getPageSource() returns this is just the code from site. My apologies

Comment: The one you have selected in the screenshot has an ID, "ROOT/2. Incident Management/Search Incidents". Is that the one? Is that ID stable? Have you tried clicking it using the ID?

Comment: I cannot reference the ID, as mentioned in the answer below I may need to trigger js but I'm seriously struggling with that!

Comment: Does it have unique text? Can you add attributes to it? (Is it your site?).

Answer (score 0):

if you know the total number of "li" tags then u can try following......

```
 jsString ="$('.x-tree-root-ct li:nth-child(4)').find("div")[0].click()"
 //or
 //jsString ="$('#ext-gen-top123 li:nth-child(4)').find("div")[0].click()"

  //execute abovee javascript using 
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  JavascriptExecutor js = null;
    if(driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
        js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript(jsString)
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Im getting this error upon compiling:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "$" is not defined. (injected script#1)

I'm using a HtmlUnitDriver, I heard this may be a problem in regards to executing and parsing javascript. But I'm new to webdrivers and dont know of any alternatives

Comment: This error is just because this post assumes jQuery is there and mapped to `$`, which clearly isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use xpath?

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='ext-gen-top281']/div[contains(@id, 'Management/Search')));
```

But acually I really don't know why you are unable to locate the element by ID.